# Loading data from a file and using it in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import pickle
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox 

Menu = Tk()

Menu.resizable(width=False, height = False)
Menu.state('zoomed')
Menu.title("Gold Farm")

Example = {"Test":"Initial"}

def database():
    with open ("accounts.pickle", "rb") as f:
        return pickle.load(f)

accounts = database()

usernameL = Label(text = "Username: ")
usernameL.place(y= 300, x = 550)
usernameB = Entry()
usernameB.place(y = 300,x = 620)

passwordL = Label(text = "Password: ")
passwordL.place(y= 330, x = 550)
passwordB = Entry(show = "*")
passwordB.place(y = 330,x = 620)

eUsername = usernameB.get()
ePassword = passwordB.get()

def confirm():
   for item in accounts:
        if eUsername in accounts and accounts[eUsername] == ePassword:
           print("Correct")
    else:
           print("False")


Login = Button(text="Login", command = confirm)
Login.place(y = 350, x = 620)
```

This is my code that completes the following:

- Asks  the user for a username and password in a tkinter window
- Sets whatever they inputted as eUsername and ePassword
- Checks if they got the right password
- Keep in mind that the 'Example' dictionary is an example of what is in the accounts files

**The problem is that when I type in the correct username and password, it still returns as false.
And so;
I would like some assistance on what I'm doing wrong, or what to fix.**

Test

```
def databaseNew():
with open("accounts.pickle", "wb") as f:
    Entry = Setup["me"] = "Tes"
    pickle.dump(Entry, f)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting any input in your code, if you call `confirm()` you will see `False` as you are iterating over every name in the dict with `for item in accounts` comparing it to an empty string.  You can also  simplify your function to `return accounts.get(eUsername) == ePassword` to check:

```
def confirm():
    print(accounts.get(eUsername) == ePassword)
```

You need to pack the Labels etc..

```
import pickle

from tkinter import *


master = Tk()

usernameL = Label(master, text="Username: ")
usernameL.pack()
usernameB = Entry(master)
usernameB.pack()
passwordL = Label(master, text="Password: ")
passwordL.pack()
passwordB = Entry(master, show="*")
passwordB.pack()


master.resizable(width=False, height=False)
master.state('normal')
master.title("Gold Farm")

def database():
    with open("accounts.pickle", "rb") as f:
        return pickle.load(f)


accounts = database()

def confirm():
    u, p = usernameB.get(), passwordB.get()
    if accounts.get(u) == p:
        print(True)
        # do whatever here
    else:
        print(False)
        #  login is bad
        m  = messagebox.askretrycancel("Invalid input")
        if not m:
             master.quit()

Login = Button(master, text="Login", command=confirm)
Login.place(y=350, x=620)
Login.pack()

mainloop()
```

This is a rough example of how to add new users to your existing dict and pickle, you can fill in the missing logic and tidy up the display with whatever you have planned and verify input:

```
import pickle

from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

usernameL = Label(master, text="Username: ")
usernameL.pack()
usernameB = Entry(master)
usernameB.pack()
passwordL = Label(master, text="Password: ")
passwordL.pack()
passwordB = Entry(master, show="*")
passwordB.pack()

master.resizable(width=False, height=False)
master.state('normal')
master.title("Gold Farm")


def database():
    with open("accounts.pickle", "rb") as f:
        return pickle.load(f)


accounts = database()

def new():
    u, p = usernameB.get(), passwordB.get()
    if u in accounts:
        m = messagebox.askretrycancel("Invalid","Username taken")
        if not m:
            master.quit()
    else:
        accounts[u] = p
        with open("accounts.pickle","wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(accounts, f)
        # do whatever


def confirm():
    u, p = usernameB.get(), passwordB.get()
    if accounts.get(u) == p:
        print(True)
        # do whatever here
    else:
        print(False)
        # do whatever when login is bad
        m  = messagebox.askretrycancel("Invalid input")
        if not m:
            master.quit()




Login = Button(master, text="Login", command=confirm)
Login.place(y=350, x=620)
Login.pack()
new_user = Button(master, text="Create acc", command=new)
new_user.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: How would I use the True and False outputs that I recieve from this? For example, running a function if its True or a print if False?

Comment: Thanks, this is fixed now. Also going abit off topic, whats the pickle way for adding to a dictionary within a file? Say I wanted to add a new account apart from Test.

Comment: @Csarg, I changed the logic, you should verify the user input in the confirm function, a messagebox would probably be a good to inform the user the details were incorrect.  Are you asking how to add keys to you dict?

Comment: Yes, I am asking how I would add differant accounts *keys* to an existing dictionary with pickle and my current file

Comment: Just `pickle.load`, add your data and `pickle.dump`.

Comment: added to my code when I treid this, take a look. It just replaces whatevers in the file with the new data.

Comment: Setup = {} (Empty dictionary)

Comment: I added a quick example of how to add a user to your existing database and pickle